# Requisites for learning about compilers?

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science, compiler-theory

I've signed up for a class on compilers coming spring, but feel extremely unprepared because I have absolutely no idea as to what the class might entail or what it might require. .

What required reading would you suggest I read up on during the break so as to be able to be able to make the most of the class?

(PS - Yes, I've ordered the dragon book.)

Comment: Tell us a bit more of your background, and about the course. undergrad or grad course?  Are you a computer science major?  Other than that, you probably really want to be comfortable with recursion -- compilers are all recursion.

Comment: Yes, Im okay with recursion(thanks racket) and have a basic understanding of BNF grammar and call stacks etc, I guess my major concern is does learning comilers involve delving into calculus/discrete mathematics related stuff or anything else one might not be expecting the first time around. Also, Comp sci major, undergrad.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Dragon Book, it's got a lot of good details, but I think it jumps around a bit.

[Language Implementation Patterns](http://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) by Terance Parr is another fine choice. It focuses a bit more on ANTLR, but its ideas are universal, and I thought Parr did an excellent job motivating the more powerful parser techniques with actual language features.

But I wouldn't worry about it too much -- after all, part of the reason for the course is that *it* will provide you with the experience in the subject.

Comment: *"Can moderators move a question into an answer on another question?"* No, we can't.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my experience. I also did a course on compilers and found it pretty difficult. You will likely be required to understand and do the basics of the followings:
Parsing the input program and detecting errors in it, constructing abstract syntax tree, semantics checking and code generation. I wouldn't consider it an important knowledge for most CS students at all however.